# Import NgxStickyfillModule from?

Tags: css-position

I'm trying to implement ngx-stickyfill (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-stickyfill) in an Angular 6 app. The instructions say "Then add the ngxStickyfill module to your app or shared module" but do not specify where to import the module from, as in

import { NgxStickyfillModule } from 'need something here';

I've tried a few guesses but nothing has worked yet.

(Ultimately, I'm trying to find a way to mimic css position:sticky for IE11, which doesn't support it.)

Answer (score 0):

```
import { NgxStickyfillModule } from 'ngx-stickyfill';
```